# What are some alternate names for characters of Arthurian legend?

Tags: arthurian

I'm working on a Homebrew D&D campaign and have always thought the legends of King Arthur and the knights of the round table were cool. I planned on basing one of my kingdoms on them but didn't want it to be immediately obvious that the characters are from the legends. I'm looking for alternate names that might hint at all the major characters and locations like Arthur, Merlin, Morgana, Lancelot, Mordred, Guinevere, Camelot, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Using any English/Welsh/Anglo, Teutonic, or Romance variant of the legendary names will likely have enough similarities to clue in your players quickly.

If you *really* want to disguise the nature of the names, try their *meanings* instead.

- Arthur: [Bear](https://www.babynames.com/name/arthur)
- Guinevere: [White
  ghost](https://www.babynames.com/name/guinevere)
- Lancelot du Lac: [Land](https://www.babynames.com/name/lancelot) (and his last name means "of the lake")
- Myrddin, or Merlin: [Sea fort](https://www.babynames.com/name/myrddin)
- Camelot is the castle, so you could go for *fair land, promised
  land,* and the like.

You could then use a second language to disguise the meaning name: Urso for bear, Fantome for ghost, Terra for land, and so on.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe use earlier Welsh forms of the names where possible?

Such as Artur/Arthur, Merlin/Myrddin, Gwenhwyfar/Guinevere, Caer Lleon/Camelot?

Answer (score 4):

While not a complete list by any means, these are some unfamiliar name variants I could think of off the top of my head.

Generally, all forms of Arthur are too close to the original to fool anyone. The best I can think of is [**Artair**](https://www.behindthename.com/name/artair), the Scottish form.
Though you could use a Welsh/Old Brythonic name like [**Arthmael**](https://www.behindthename.com/name/armel) ("bear prince").

Morgana/Morgan le Fay is similarly difficult to obscure, since her earliest name is still [**Morgen**](https://www.behindthename.com/name/morgan-2). **Marguel** is the most unfamiliar form in [this list](https://www.nightbringer.se/a_morganlefay.html).

Guinevere has many variants. Some of the more unfamiliar ones may be [**Guanhumara**](https://forvo.com/tag/guinevere/) (Geoffrey of Monmouth's rendering in Latin), [**Wenneuereia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinevere#Name) (used by Gerald of Wales), and [**Findabair**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findabair) (the Irish cognate). [**Winlogee**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maleagant) is presumably Guinevere in a carving on the archivolt of Modena Cathedral in Italy.

For Gawain, there's [**Gwalchmei**](https://forvo.com/word/gwalchmei/) (Welsh), [**Gualguanus**](https://forvo.com/word/gualguanus/) (Geoffrey of Monmouth's rendering in Latin), and [**Gauvain**](https://forvo.com/word/gauvain/) (French). [**Balbhuaidh**](https://forvo.com/word/balbhuaidh/) is the Irish form.

[**Arnive**](https://forvo.com/word/arnive/) was the name of Arthur's mother, Igraine, in [Wolfram von Eschenbach's *Parzival*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igraine).

[**Bedwyr**](https://forvo.com/search/Bedwyr/) is Bedivere's original Welsh name. [**Beduerus**](https://forvo.com/word/beduerus/) is Geoffrey of Monmouth's rendering in Latin.

[**Galath**](http://www.maryjones.us/ctexts/triads4.html) and [**Lanslod**](https://forvo.com/word/lanslod_lak/) for Galahad and Lancelot.

[**Medraut**](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/camelot/text/arthurian-references-in-annales-cambriae) is one of [many variants](https://forvo.com/tag/mordred/) of Mordred. It's also the original.

[**Myrddin**](https://forvo.com/search/Myrddin/) is the Welsh name for Merlin.

In place of Camelot, there is a pretty decent list of courts Arthur had, in Welsh sources: [**Caerleon**](https://forvo.com/word/caerleon/) (his capital [according to Geoffrey of Monmouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caerleon#Arthurian_legend)), [**Mynyw**](https://forvo.com/word/mynyw/), [**Pen Rhionydd**](https://forvo.com/word/pen_rhionydd/), and [**Celliwig**](https://forvo.com/word/celliwig/)/[**Gelliwic**](https://forvo.com/word/gelliwic/).